# Concat fields in load statement

Tags: qlikview

I have a simple load statement:

```
LOAD FIELDA,
     FIELDB,
     FIELDC,
     FIELDD,
     FIELDE
FROM
[C:\Users\XXX\data.QVD]
(qvd);
```

This loads all the data fine.

If i add an expression into a straight table it gives me the concatenated field:

```
 concat(FIELDA&'.'&FIELDB&'.'&FIELDC&'.'&IF(Isnull(FIELDD), '0', FIELDD)&'.'&IF(Isnull(FIELDE), '0', FIELDE)) as MERGED
```

This works, however if i try and add a concatenated field from the load statement i get an error:

```
LOAD FIELDA,
     FIELDB,
     FIELDC,
     FIELDD,
     FIELDE,
     concat(FIELDA&'.'&FIELDB&'.'&FIELDC&'.'&IF(Isnull(FIELDD), '0', FIELDD)&'.'&IF(Isnull(FIELDE), '0', FIELDE)) as MERGED
FROM
[C:\Users\XXX\data.QVD]
(qvd);
```

> Invalid expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `concat` function is an aggregation function so it wants a group by to know what to do, hence the Invalid expression error. In the front end the dimension you choose for the chart serves that purpose.

If you just want to concat the fields line for line just remove the `concat` function.

```
FIELDA&'.'&FIELDB&'.'&FIELDC&'.'&IF(Isnull(FIELDD), '0', FIELDD)&'.'&IF(Isnull(FIELDE), '0', FIELDE) as MERGED
```

The actual use of the concat function would be something like this, run it and see the difference between MERGE and MERGE2;

A:

```
LOAD * INLINE [
    FieldA, FieldB,FieldC
    1, 2,1
    1, 0,1
    2, 9,1
    2, 4,1
];
```

B:

```
load FieldA,     
     concat(FieldB,'|') as MERGE     
Resident A
group by FieldA;
```

C:

```
load FieldA,
     FieldB,
     FieldC,
     FieldA&'.'&FieldB&'.'&FieldC as MERGE2
resident A;

drop table A;
```